# How to split the rows into column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using `SQL Server 2000`

Table1

```
ID

A001
A002
A003
A004
A005
A006
A007
....
....
A028
```

From the above table, i want to split the 3 rows into 3 column, order by `id`

Rows display like this

Expected Output

```
id1 id2 id3

A001 A002 A003
A004 A005 A006
A007 A008 A009
...
...
A025 A026 A027
A028 null null
```

ID is not fixed, id may contain like this also (`01A or A001 or 1A1 or etc....`)

Table 1 row count is not fixed, it may goes more than 100 rows also. Column 3 is fixed. How to make a query for the above condition.

Need Query Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

- Replace `A` with nothing in those IDs and convert them to integers
- Write three `SELECT` statements where the condition will be integer ID calculated in above step %3 is 1, 2, 0 respectively, to yield the records in each row.
- Now, we need to JOIN the results of these three SELECT statements and if you were on SQL Server 2005, then `ROW_NUMBER()` would have been handy, but since you are on SQL Server 2000, you would use `IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1)` to generate row numbers for each row in these SELECT statements and JOIN on this value.

But since `IDENTITY` can be used in `SELECT` only with `INTO` clause, you would end up with temporary tables that contain each column and join on them.

```
SELECT IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS 'RowNum', ID FROM INTO #Row1 Table1
WHERE CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(ID, 'A', '')) % 3 = 1

SELECT IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS 'RowNum', ID FROM INTO #Row2 Table1
WHERE CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(ID, 'A', '')) % 3 = 2

SELECT IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS 'RowNum', ID FROM INTO #Row3 Table1
WHERE CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(ID, 'A', '')) % 3 = 0

SELECT 
    r1.ID id1,
    r2.ID id2,
    r3.ID id3
FROM
    #Row1 r1
    FULL OUTER JOIN #Row2 r2
    ON r1.RowNum = r2.RowNum
    FULL OUTER JOIN #Row3 r3
    ON r3.RowNum = r3.RowNum

DROP TABLE #Row1
DROP TABLE #Row2
DROP TABLE #Row3
```

If you were on SQL Server 2005 or higher, all this could have been done in a single query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    R1.ID,
    R2.ID,
    R3.ID
FROM 
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RowNum, ID 
        FROM ATABLE 
        WHERE 
            CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(ID, 'A', '')) % 3 = 1
    ) AS R1
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RowNum, ID 
        FROM ATABLE 
        WHERE 
            CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(ID, 'A', '')) % 3 = 2
    ) AS R2
    ON R1.RowNum = R2.RowNum
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RowNum, ID 
        FROM ATABLE 
        WHERE 
            CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(ID, 'A', '')) % 3 = 0
   ) AS R3
    ON R2.RowNum = R3.RowNum
```

Comment: @Gopal, Then you would insert them into an intermediate table with IDENTITY column and perform the modulus operation on that value instead of on the ID.